# ADXL345 Arduino UNO Activity Inactivity interrupt

Tags: interrupt

I have DATA_READY, Activity and Inactivity interrupts mapped from INT1 to INT0 on the arduino. DATA_READY works fine, the problem is Activity and Inactivity are always set to 0 in the INT_SOURCE register. I have set up the threshold for activity and inactivity and the time of inactivity. I would like the algorithm to run when DATA_READY and Activity interrupts are 1 and do nothing when Inactivity is 1 (activity is 0). When Activity is 0 the accelerometer should go automatically in sleep mode and wakes up if activity is detected.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_ADXL345_U.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/power.h>


#define F_CPU 16000000UL 



int state=0; //0--active detecting; 1--sleeping
int state_count=0; //sleeping trigger between 2 states
double mag[40];
int i=0;
double acc_rate[39];
int hunt_sub=0;
int exit_marker=-10,trough_marker=-30,peak_marker=-10;
volatile int sensor_update=0, active_mode=0;//active_mode=0, inactive; 1--active;      sensor_update=0, no new data; 1--new data comes
byte buff[1] ;


volatile unsigned long time=0, time0=0,time_dis=0,time_array[40]={0};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Read ADXL345 registers
void readFrom(int device, byte address, int num, byte buff[]) {
Wire.beginTransmission(device); //start transmission to device 
Wire.write(address);        //sends address to read from
Wire.endTransmission(); //end transmission

Wire.beginTransmission(device); //start transmission to device (initiate again)
Wire.requestFrom(device, num);    // request 1 byte from device

int i = 0;
while(Wire.available())    //device may send less than requested (abnormal)
{ 
buff[i] = Wire.read(); // receive a byte
i++;
}
Wire.endTransmission(); //end transmission
}

//Write to ADXL345 registers
void writeTo(int device, byte address, byte val) {
Wire.beginTransmission(device); //start transmission to device 
Wire.write(address);        // send register address
Wire.write(val);        // send value to write
Wire.endTransmission(); //end transmission
}



//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//ISR function



void interrupt(void){

readFrom(0x53, 0x30, 1, buff); 

if(buff & 0b00010000){
  active_mode=1;//active state
}
if(buff & 0b00001000){ 
  active_mode=0;//inactivity state
}

if(buff & 0b10000000){
sensor_update=1;//DATA_READY each 10ms  
}

}




/* Assign a unique ID to this sensor at the same time */
Adafruit_ADXL345_Unified accel = Adafruit_ADXL345_Unified(12345);





void setup(void) 
{
if (F_CPU == 16000000) clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);
Serial.begin(9600);
//Serial.println("Accelerometer Test"); Serial.println("");

pinMode(4, OUTPUT);// buzzer output pin
pinMode(2, INPUT);

/* Initialise the sensor */
if(!accel.begin())
{
/* There was a problem detecting the ADXL345 ... check your connections */
//Serial.println("Ooops, no ADXL345 detected ... Check your wiring!");
while(1);
}

/* Set the range to whatever is appropriate for your project */
accel.setRange(ADXL345_RANGE_8_G);
accel.setDataRate(ADXL345_DATARATE_100_HZ);
// displaySetRange(ADXL345_RANGE_8_G);
// displaySetRange(ADXL345_RANGE_4_G);
// displaySetRange(ADXL345_RANGE_2_G);

/* Display some basic information on this sensor */
//displaySensorDetails();

/* Display additional settings (outside the scope of sensor_t) */
//displayDataRate();
//displayRange();
//Serial.println("");

//Create an interrupt that will trigger when a tap is detected.

writeTo(0x53, 0x2D, 59);//POWER_CTL  auto sleep, link, 1hz rate
writeTo(0x53, 0x2C, 10);//BW_RATE low power mode off rate 100Hz
writeTo(0x53, 0x2E, 0);// disable interrupt

attachInterrupt(0, interrupt, RISING);

writeTo(0x53, 0x2F, 0); //map to to INT1
writeTo(0x53, 0x2E, 152); //enable data_ready, activity, inactivity
writeTo(0x53, 0x25, 18); //THRESH_INACT  ((11/9.8)*1000)/62.5
writeTo(0x53, 0x26, 60); //TIME_INACT    one minute
writeTo(0x53, 0x24, 21); //THRESH_ACT    ((13/9.8)*1000)/62.5
writeTo(0x53, 0x27, 0); //ACT_INACT_CTL   dc coupled, use only magnitude.


}

void loop(void) 
{

readFrom(0x53, 0x30, 1, buff);
Serial.print("buff: "); Serial.print(buff); Serial.print("  ");

sensors_event_t event; 
do{ //clear DATA_READY
accel.getEvent(&event);
readFrom(0x53, 0x30, 1, buff);
}while(buff & 0b10000000);




if(sensor_update==1 && active_mode==1){
//When sensor_update is set to 1 in the ISR,the algorithm process the data from the accelerometer being updated every 10ms(100Hz)
//rest of algorithm is here
 sensor_update=0;//reset



}


}
```

Edit:

I have modified the program to check in the loop whether the different flags are set and only the DATA_READY is. Activity and Inactivity are never set.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_ADXL345_U.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/power.h>


#define F_CPU 16000000UL 



int state=0; //0--active detecting; 1--sleeping
int state_count=0; //sleeping trigger between 2 states
double mag[40];
int i=0;
double acc_rate[39];
int hunt_sub=0;
int exit_marker=-10,trough_marker=-30,peak_marker=-10;
volatile int sensor_update=0, active_mode=0;//active_mode=0, inactive; 1--active;     sensor_update=0, no new data; 1--new data comes
byte buff[1] ;


volatile unsigned long time=0, time0=0,time_dis=0,time_array[40]={0};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Read ADXL345 registers
void readFrom(int device, byte address, int num, byte buff[]) {
Wire.beginTransmission(device); //start transmission to device 
Wire.write(address);        //sends address to read from
Wire.endTransmission(); //end transmission

Wire.beginTransmission(device); //start transmission to device (initiate again)
Wire.requestFrom(device, num);    // request 1 byte from device

int i = 0;
while(Wire.available())    //device may send less than requested (abnormal)
{ 
buff[i] = Wire.read(); // receive a byte
i++;
}
Wire.endTransmission(); //end transmission
}

//Write to ADXL345 registers
void writeTo(int device, byte address, byte val) {
Wire.beginTransmission(device); //start transmission to device 
Wire.write(address);        // send register address
Wire.write(val);        // send value to write
Wire.endTransmission(); //end transmission
}



//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//ISR function



void interrupt(void){


//    
//    if(buff & 0b00010000){
//      active_mode=1;//active state
//    }
//    if(buff & 0b00001000){ 
//      active_mode=0;//inactivity state
//    }
//    
//    if(buff & 0b10000000){
//    sensor_update=1;//DATA_READY each 10ms  
//    }

}




/* Assign a unique ID to this sensor at the same time */
Adafruit_ADXL345_Unified accel = Adafruit_ADXL345_Unified(12345);





void setup(void) 
{
if (F_CPU == 16000000) clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);
Serial.begin(9600);
//Serial.println("Accelerometer Test"); Serial.println("");

pinMode(4, OUTPUT);// buzzer output pin
pinMode(2, INPUT);

/* Initialise the sensor */
if(!accel.begin())
{
/* There was a problem detecting the ADXL345 ... check your connections */
//Serial.println("Ooops, no ADXL345 detected ... Check your wiring!");
while(1);
}

/* Set the range to whatever is appropriate for your project */
accel.setRange(ADXL345_RANGE_8_G);
accel.setDataRate(ADXL345_DATARATE_100_HZ);

//Create an interrupt that will trigger when a tap is detected.


  writeTo(0x53, 0x2D, 59);//POWER_CTL  auto sleep, link, 1hz rate
  writeTo(0x53, 0x2C, 10);//BW_RATE low power mode off rate 100Hz
  writeTo(0x53, 0x2E, 0);// disable interrupt

  attachInterrupt(0, interrupt, RISING);

  writeTo(0x53, 0x2F, 0); //map to to INT1
  writeTo(0x53, 0x2E, 152); //enable data_ready, activity, inactivity
  // writeTo(0x53, 0x25, 18); //THRESH_INACT  ((11/9.8)*1000)/62.5
  writeTo(0x53, 0x27, 119); //ACT_INACT_CTL   dc coupled, use only magnitude.
  writeTo(0x53, 0x25, 5); //THRESH_INACT  ((3.0625/9.8)*1000)/62.5
  writeTo(0x53, 0x26, 1); //TIME_INACT    one minute
  writeTo(0x53, 0x24, 21); //THRESH_ACT    ((12.8625/9.8)*1000)/62.5

  }

  void loop(void) 
  {

  if(digitalRead(2)) {

  readFrom(0x53, 0x30, 1, buff);

  //Serial.print("### ");

  //Serial.println(interruptSource, BIN);


  if(buff[0] & 0b10000000) {

  Serial.println("### DATA_READY");

  }


  if(buff[0] & 0b00001000) {

  Serial.println("### Inacitivity");

  }

  if(buff[0] & 0b00010000) {

  Serial.println("### activity");

  // we don't need to put the device in sleep because we set the AUTO_SLEEP bit to 1 in R_POWER_CTL

  // set the LOW_POWER bit to 1 in R_BW_RATE: with this we get worst measurements but we save power

}


delay(150);

}


sensors_event_t event; 
do{ //clear DATA_READY
accel.getEvent(&event);
readFrom(0x53, 0x30, 1, buff);
}while(buff & 0b10000000);




if(sensor_update==1 && active_mode==1){
//When sensor_update is set to 1 in the ISR,the algorithm process the data from the accelerometer being updated every 10ms(100Hz)
//rest of algorithm is here
 sensor_update=0;//reset



}


}
```

Comment: updated code ..

Comment: from the datasheet apparently reading the INT_SOURCE registers clears the Activity and Inactivity flags, in that case it would be normal to read o for them. As an alternative, I mapped the activity interrupt from INT2 of ADXL to INT1 of the arduino. active_mode=1 inside the second interrupt function, the first is for data_ready where sensor_update is set to 1. Even with this sensor_update and active_mode always reads 0. Confusing!